# How to Keep Frozen Panes from Scrolling? - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a sheet that has some columns that are frozen, but I don't want the rows in those columns to scroll with the rest of the sheet when I scroll down. For example, I want A1:D40 to be frozen, and when I scroll down through the sheet, I want A41:D(end of sheet) to slide behind A1:D40. Is this possible? And could the the same thing be done for rows at the same time? I'm hoping to use this to make a control panel type thing and i'd rather the buttons and what not always be visible.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: use a user form and not part of the work sheet.

Comment: Is there a userform that I can still use the worksheet while it's open?

Comment: Yes, it just needs the modal form set correctly.

Comment: Cool, thanks, i'll try that. Is it possible to hide the title bar and close button at the top?

Comment: I believe so, it has been a while since I used user forms in Excel.

Comment: ill do some research. thanks, you've be a big help